# axios: stop automatic sorting of objects based on keys

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, axios

I am gettting an api response using axios.

I am sending the api response sorted w.r.t name `http://localhost:8000/api/ingredients/ordering=name`

The actual object sent is as below from my server.

```
{
    2:{"id":2,"name":"anil"},
    1:{"id":1,"name":"sant"},
    3:{"id":3,"name":"vino"}
}
```

or pass the key as string instead of integer

```
{
    "2":{"id":2,"name":"anil"},
    "1":{"id":1,"name":"sant"},
    "3":{"id":3,"name":"vino"}
}
```

or key as alphanumeric

```
{
    "a2":{"id":2,"name":"anil"},
    "a1":{"id":1,"name":"sant"},
    "a3":{"id":3,"name":"vino"}
}
```

what axios is doing is sorting the objects w.r.t keys and the names are not in sorted order

```
{
    1:{"id":1,"name":"sant"},
    2:{"id":2,"name":"anil"},
    3:{"id":3,"name":"vino"}
}
```

or if key is alpha numeric

```
{
    a1:{"id":1,"name":"sant"},
    a2:{"id":2,"name":"anil"},
    a3:{"id":3,"name":"vino"}
}
```

How to stop this

I dont want in array format the list because i have to update the individual objects later based on the id. This representation is easy. I am using reactjs state.

Comment: JavaScript objects are not ordered.If you want objects in certain order, use array.

Answer (score 3):

There is answer here [Does JavaScript Guarantee Object Property Order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order/23202095#23202095) among other that says:

most browsers returns properties in the same order as they were inserted, but it was explicitly not guaranteed behaviour so shouldn't have been relied upon.

The [ECMAScript specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-262.pdf) used to say:

> The mechanics and order of enumerating the properties ... is not
>   specified.

However in ES2015 and later non-integer keys will be returned in insertion order.

So don't rely on order of an object keys. If you don't worry about ES5 you can try to use non-integer keys - strings for instance but note that strings like '1' are not suitable http://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=164.

You can find on the page of the answer also:

If you rely on insertion order, you are outside the ECMAScript spec, but within the de-facto standard of common browser behavior as long as your keys don't parse as integers.

**UPDATE**

Short answer is axios doesn't sort keys of an object

https://jsfiddle.net/zabq841t/

```
axios.get('/echo/js/?js={a2: 1, a1: 0}')
    .then((res) => {
        //res.data is {a2: 1, a1: 0}
    })
```

You can get sorted version because of old browser or your server. Take a look fiddle if it works for you then probably you have 'issue' on server side. You need to provide more details about you server app.

Answer (score 1):

This is an expected behavior for objects in JavaScript.

If you want to have the order intact, use `Arrays`, So your example would turn out like this,

```
const obj = [{name:"two"},{name:"three"},{name:"one"}];
```

If you need to pass keys, then reorder it in this way,
[image]

## Edited

Back to your edited version, say you want to update your object based on ID and this is your provided json,

```
{
    a1:{"id":1,"name":"sant"},
    a2:{"id":2,"name":"anil"},
    a3:{"id":3,"name":"vino"}
}
```

Nothing will stop you from doing so, if you want to change details for an object with `id:2`, you can do the following to get the key `a2`,

```
const key = Object.entries(obj).find(entry => entry[1].key === 2)[0];
const desiredElement = obj(key);
```

Breakdown of the code,

```
Object.entries(obj) // get entries from object
.find(entry) //where entry[0] is key, entry[1] is value/object
entry[1].id=== 2 // return the element that has id === 2
[0] // since entry[0] is key, then it would hold a2 here
```

Now we can use the key as we want like, `Obj[key]`, and update it as well.