# How to prevent axios to sort by key?

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, axios

I would like the years to still be displayed desc order. In my request, the years and correctly sorted.

My PHP controller returns a json like this:

```
{  
   "2018":[  
      {  
         "id":25071,

      },
      {  
         "id":35037,
      }
   ],
   "2017":[  
      {  
         "id":20449,
      },
      {  
         "id":25797
      }
   ],
   "2016":[  
      {  
         "id":20419,
      },
      {  
         "id":25778
      }  
   ]
}
```

But when I get in in my vue component

```
getYears: function(){
    axios.get('/blablabla/').then(
        response => {
            console.log(response.data);
            this.years=response.data;
        }
    );
}
```

I get this result

{2008: Array(1), 2010: Array(5), 2011: Array(7), 2012: Array(7), 2013: Array(4), 2014: Array(5), 2015: Array(8), 2016: Array(4), 2017: Array(6), 2018: Array(6)}
2008: (...)
2010: (...)
2011: (...)
2012: (...)
2013: (...)
2014: (...)
2015: (...)
2016: (...)
2017: (...)
2018: (...)

How can I prevent it to change the order?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: That's weird, do you have any sorting on client side? Maybe in some axios global config?

Comment: If you require a specific order, perhaps use an array?

Comment: The object is convenient beaucause then I can just display it in the table. But I didn't add any specific configuration, no

Comment: Well actually, adding ' ' (a blank space) after the year work. (casting it to a string doesn't though). Strange, but I guess I can just use this... :)

Comment: if this is a mongodb request you can project the sort in the route by appending `.sort({year : -1})` to the query statement .. assuming `year` is the name of the document holding the years

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thats not an axios problem. In ES2015 non-integer keys where returned in insertion order. Browser things. You made it into a string, so its not an integer anymore.

If you want to read more about it: [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47727428/axios-stop-automatic-sorting-of-objects-based-on-keys)